# Criar Servidor no pgAdmin 4 com IP externo

Tags: postgresql, servidor

Estou tentando criar um servidor com IP externo no meu pgAdmin 4, porém ocorre o seguinte erro quando tento salvá-lo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acessando o arquivo `pg_hba.conf` verifiquei que o mesmo esta assim atualmente:

TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

IPv4 local connections:
host    all     all         192.168.1.130/32             md5
host    all         all     0.0.0.0/0       trust

IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5

Já tentei alterar a linha **host    all     all         192.168.1.130/32             md5** para **host postgres postgres 192.168.1.130/32 md5**, mas o erro persiste;

Se tiverem alguma sugestão.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri que o erro na verdade não estava na minha máquina e sim no Servidor onde o **PostgreSQL** estava instalado, lá as configurações do arquivo `pg_hba.conf` estava errada a configuração de hosts que permitira acesso ao banco.

Solução encontrada:

Alterar a linha:

**host all all 192.168.1.130/32 trust**

Para:

**host postgres postgres 192.168.1.130/32 md5**